# Jet API bulk JSON upload: The magic number in GZip header is not correct

Tags: python, python-requests, jet.com-apis

I attempted to contact Jet directly and was told to “try using 7zip to gzip the file” and then received no further responses (despite further questions).

Here's the error code:

```
"error_excerpt": [
    "Error parsing file: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."
  ],
```

Here's what I'm trying:

```
def file_upload_url(self, url, filename, data):
    headers = {"x-ms-blob-type": "blockblob"}
    magic_number = open(filename, 'rb').read(2) # shows that magic number is correct for .gz file
    print `magic_number`
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        file_data=f.read()
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, files={ "test.json.gz": file_data }) 
    # i've also tried data={"test.json.gz": file_data}
```

Which then you check with another call. The file was gzipped from the Ubuntu command line (to rule out Python's gzip module causing the problem).

Here is the documentation provided: https://developer.jet.com/docs/

I've implemented every other function without the slightest hiccup but this is just not working. Only thing I can think of is that I'm somehow sending the file data incorrectly. But I can't seem to figure out how.

The `.json` file was confirmed to be valid from the Jet representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out the answer. Must make sure to ONLY put the binary data (not a dictionary, like for files) inside the data parameter in requests.

making it:

```
def file_upload_url(self, url, filename, data):
    headers = {"x-ms-blob-type": "blockblob"}
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        file_data=f.read()
    response = requests.put(url, headers=headers, data=file_data)
```

Nice and easy.